# Sitecore reset item layout

Tags: layout, sitecore, reset

How can I programmatically 'Reset' the layout of the item? This is possible through the Sitecore client from the 'Presentation' tab. I haven't been able to find an example of this anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a pretty basic way to do what you ask.

```
Item item; // your item here... Sitecore.Context.Item perhaps?

using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item["__renderings"]))
    {
        using (new Sitecore.Data.Items.EditContext(item))
        {
            item.Fields["__renderings"].Reset();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Sean, did you mean `__renderings` instead?